# How Can I move this Flex-Box Item to be next of the img?

Tags: css, position, flexbox

[Plz see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSy3w.png)

How Can I move this Flex-Box Item to be next of the img ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSy3w.png

```
 <div class="brif fb">
                <div class="sml-con"><img class="sml-thumb" src="images/chosen/edward.jpg" alt=""></div>
                <h3>The WhiteBeard Pirates</h3>
                <div class="trai"> <i class="fa fa-video-camera mr5"></i> <span>Trailer</span></div>
                <p>Meet the most unusual baby, known only as "Baby", who wears a suit, speaks with the voice and wit of Alec Baldwin, as he teams up with is seven-year old brother to stop the dastardly plot of the CEO of Puppy Co.</p>
```

css

```
   `.brif { width:69%; flex-wrap: wrap; padding:17px; align-items: flex-
start; /* prevent the childs from taking full height */  }

.brif .sml-con { width: 140px; height: 210px;  }

.brif .sml-thumb { width:100%; height:100%; }

.brif h3 { padding: 9px 15px; }

.brif .trai { background:  #0397D6; padding: 5px 9px; border-radius:10px; 
margin:5px 0; }

.brif .trai i{ margin-right:1px; }`
```

Comment: Post a minimal working code snippet and we will be able to suggest a proper solution

Comment: I've done it, could you remove the negative raiting ?, thanks

Comment: I didn't down vote

Comment: May I ask why you removed your accept? If you post a comment if there were something what went wrong with the answer I gave, I would be able to adjust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a wrapper around the text `<div class="wrapper">`, add `display: flex;` and remove `flex-wrap: wrap;` they will stay side-by-side

```css
.brif {
  width: 69%;
  display: flex;
  padding: 17px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  /* prevent the childs from taking full height */
}

.brif .sml-con {
  width: 140px;
  height: 210px;
}

.brif .sml-thumb {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.brif h3 {
  padding: 9px 15px;
}

.brif .trai {
  background: #0397D6;
  padding: 5px 9px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.brif .trai i {
  margin-right: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="brif fb">
  <div class="sml-con">
    <img class="sml-thumb" src="images/chosen/edward.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h3>The WhiteBeard Pirates</h3>
    <div class="trai">
      <i class="fa fa-video-camera mr5"></i>
      <span>Trailer</span>
    </div>
    <p>Meet the most unusual baby, known only as "Baby", who wears a suit, speaks with the voice and wit of Alec Baldwin, as he teams up with is seven-year old brother to stop the dastardly plot of the CEO of Puppy Co.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```